# Discrete Low-Pass Filter

Tags: simulink

After passing my data through a discrete derivative it gives me very noisy peaked data but I would like to change this without compromising system stability.

How is it possible to implement a discrete low pass filter in simulink without the use of a subsystem. I havent been able to find a block to do this.

However if this isn't possible how would i model a subsystem to give the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

The `Discrete Library` has both a [Discrete Transfer Function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/discretetransferfcn.html) and [Discrete Filter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/discretefilter.html) block, either of which can be used for a discrete filter - nothing to do with subsystems.

Note that you should almost never model using derivatives - discrete or continuous - because it will introduce noise. And that there will always be a trade off between performance and stability, so asking how to do something without compromising system stability isn't really a sensible question.